# Edit existing shipping address on checkout page not working - magento 2

Tags: magento2

The feature required is to allow the logged in user to edit any of his previously added address on the checkout page.

Initially, the edit option was not there against the existing addresses. I changed the following lines in the following file

> /Magento_Customer/web/js/model/customer/address.js

```
 isEditable: function ()
 {
     return true;       
 },
```

In doing so the edit link does appear on the addresses. ( please see the screenshot )
[image: Edit Link for previously added addresses]

Now the problem is when I click on the edit link, the popup which gets displayed doesn't have the fields populated with the address selected ( please check the screenshot below ). If I fill the fields up and save the address, it gets added as a new address.

[image: Blank Fields on selecting Edit]

**Another point to notice here:**
If I add a new address and save it and without refreshing/redirecting I click on edit then the form fields populate properly and gets saved properly as well.

Does anyone have any suggestion or solution as to how to allow edit of the old addresses properly on the checkout step?

Comment: sorry don't know how that answers my question. i asked about editing any previously added address on the checkout page.

Comment: I am also getting this issue.
Did you solve this ?

Comment: found this also under the exact same conditions and was also wondering if anyone else figured it out yet

Comment: @S.P. Did you find it out? (if you can remeber)